# What does empty array.slice(0).push(anything) mean?

Tags: javascript, slice

I want to clone a new array from an existing one and push in an element.
Unfortunately, the existing array is an empty one, so it's like:

```
[].slice().push(65)
```

the output of above expression is 1.

Why is it 1?

Comment: [MDN `push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push): *The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.* You need to do it in two steps, not one with that pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#push()` returns the length of the resultant array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) Since you're pushing a single value onto an empty array, the length of the result will indeed be 1.

If you want to see the updated array as output, you'll need to save a reference to it since `push()` does not return a reference:

```
var arr = [].slice();
arr.push(65);
console.log(arr); // [ 65 ]
```

Comment: then there's no easier way to have a new array and push in one more element? I have to create a variable to store [].slice() first, and then call push method on the new array ?

Comment: @Aaron Shen: If you really want to avoid that, you can concat instead: `[].concat(65)` It even saves you the need to clone the original array using `slice()`.

Answer (score 2):

Changing my comment to an answer:

[MDN `push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push): *The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.*

You need to do it in two steps, not one with that pattern.

```
var temp = [].slice();
temp.push(65);
console.log(temp);
```

If you want to do it in one line, look into [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [].concat(a,64);
console.log(b);
```